# Getting the inverse function

Tags: inverse-function

I have a small problem, I can't get the inverse function. I tried to solve it using InverseFunction, breaking it into parts, but unfortunately it didn’t work. I also tried solving it using Solve.
The function itself:

```
H0 = 140;
B0 = 1.29;
s = 6.3;
\[Beta] = 0.7;
Bm[Hm_] := B0 Hm/H0 (1 + (Abs[Hm/H0])^s)^(-1/(s + \[Beta]));
```

I got the formula, but it doesn't work:

```
H0 Bm/B0 ((Bm - 1)^(1/s)/B0)^-(s + \[Beta]);
```

I ask for your help, thank you.

Comment: You only need a numerical inverse  function?

Comment: How accurate do you need the inverse? And what definition range? Your function is essentially linear over a large range. The term in the denominator has a factor of 10^-14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is not invertibl algebraically.

```
      Plot[Bm[Hm], {Hm, 0, 140}]
```

[image: PlotBm(Hn)]

```
      Assuming[{0.1 < y < 1.2 \.08}, 
         Solve[B0 Hm/H0 (1 + (Abs[Hm/H0])^s)^(-1/(s + \[Beta])) == y, Hm]]
```

Reduced to the essential variables, the defining equation is
$$x^s=\text{B0}^{\frac{1}{\beta +s}} \quad  x^{\frac{1}{\beta +s}} \quad y^{\frac{1}{\beta +s}}-1$$

Use numerical Interpolation, that can be trivially inverted by exchange of the axes.

Comment: thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

H0 = 140;
B0 = 129/100;
s = 63/10;
β = 7/10;

Bm[Hm_] := B0 Hm/H0 (1 + (Abs[Hm/H0])^s)^(-1/(s + β));
```

`Bm` has odd symmetry:

```
Bm[-Hm] == -Bm[Hm]

(* True *)

invBm[bm_?NumericQ] := Sign[bm]*NSolveValues[
    {Bm[x] == Abs[bm], x >= 0}, x][[1]]

Show[
 ParametricPlot[{Bm[Hm], Hm}, {Hm, -140, 140},
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {Bm, Hm}),
  AspectRatio -> 1],
 Plot[invBm[bm], {bm, -1.2, 1.2},
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, how can I get the formula in analytical form?

Comment: As @RolandF indicated, you can't.